# Is there a utility to read environment variables from an env file and then run a command (more lightweight than foreman)?

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables

[`foreman`](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) can read .env files and set environment variables from the contents, and then run a program

e.g. `foreman run -e vars.env myprogram`

...but it does a lot of other things (and is primarily concerned with starting things using its Procfile format).

Is there a simpler (Linux/Unix) tool that's just focussed on reading .env files and executing a command with the new environment?

Example environment file (from http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT ):

```
FOO=bar
BAZ=qux
```

Comment: Can you post an example .env file? I suspect `bash .env` or `sh .env` may work?

Comment: @IVlint67 I've improved the question a little.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can source the environment file in the active shell and run the program:

```
sh -ac ' . ./.env; /usr/local/bin/someprogram'
```

The `-a` switch exports all variables, so that they are available to the program.

Comment: `bash -ac 'source .env && ./program'`

Comment: @fiatjaf Why would you use bash in this case if the POSIX shell does the job and you need no feature that actually requires bash? Furthermore, bash is not available by default on all systems (e.g. FreeBSD).

Comment: Oh, right, makes sense, I think your way is better, then. I was just providing the Bash alternative because I felt more comfortable writing it.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is `envdir`:

> envdir runs another program with environment modified according to files in a specified directory.

- The daemontools original: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/envdir.html
- A python port: https://github.com/jezdez/envdir

Comment: This post mentions some complementary features between `envdir`, `runit`, and `chpst`; namely ability to have changed env vars reflect in the state of the process being run. The post is about docker but it's not limited to docker. https://blog.ghaering.de/post/docker-as-vm/ [ archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20190321165332/https://blog.ghaering.de/post/docker-as-vm/ ]

Answer (score 2):

I tried `source .env` and it worked like a charm. Unfortunately, none of the other solutions posted here worked for me.

Comment: This works only for valid bash (strings like `export KEY=VALUE`, not `KEY=VALUE`)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
env $(cat .env | tr "\\n" " ") myprogram
```

but obviously doesn't check the format of the `.env` file for correctness, which a utility program would do.

Comment: 1) The `cat` is not necessary, just write `tr "\\n" " " < .env` 2) This breaks if multi-line assignments are used.